# sushi swap not returning

Tags: node.js, blockchain, smartcontracts

```
// Uniswap Factory Contract: https://etherscan.io/address/0xC0AEe478e3658e2610c5F7A4A2E1777cE9e4f2Ac#code
const UNISWAP_FACTORY_ABI = [{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeToSetter","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"PairCreated","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"allPairs","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"allPairsLength","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"}],"name":"createPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"feeTo","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"feeToSetter","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"getPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"migrator","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"pairCodeHash","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeTo","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeTo","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeToSetter","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeToSetter","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_migrator","type":"address"}],"name":"setMigrator","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]
const UNISWAP_FACTORY_ADDRESS = '0xC0AEe478e3658e2610c5F7A4A2E1777cE9e4f2Ac'
const uniswapFactoryContract = new web3.eth.Contract(UNISWAP_FACTORY_ABI, UNISWAP_FACTORY_ADDRESS)

// console.log("uniswapFactoryContract", uniswapFactoryContract)

// // Uniswap Exchange Template: https://etherscan.io/address/0x09cabec1ead1c0ba254b09efb3ee13841712be14#code
const UNISWAP_EXCHANGE_ABI = [{"name": "TokenPurchase", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "buyer", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_sold", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "EthPurchase", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "buyer", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "AddLiquidity", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "provider", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_amount", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "token_amount", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "RemoveLiquidity", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "provider", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_amount", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "token_amount", "indexed": true}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "Transfer", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_from", "indexed": true}, {"type": "address", "name": "_to", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value", "indexed": false}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "Approval", "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_owner", "indexed": true}, {"type": "address", "name": "_spender", "indexed": true}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value", "indexed": false}], "anonymous": false, "type": "event"}, {"name": "setup", "outputs": [], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 175875}, {"name": "addLiquidity", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "min_liquidity"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 82616}, {"name": "removeLiquidity", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "amount"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 116814}, {"name": "__default__", "outputs": [], "inputs": [], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function"}, {"name": "ethToTokenSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 12757}, {"name": "ethToTokenTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 12965}, {"name": "ethToTokenSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 50463}, {"name": "ethToTokenTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": true, "type": "function", "gas": 50671}, {"name": "tokenToEthSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 47503}, {"name": "tokenToEthTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 47712}, {"name": "tokenToEthSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 50175}, {"name": "tokenToEthTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 50384}, {"name": "tokenToTokenSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 51007}, {"name": "tokenToTokenTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 51098}, {"name": "tokenToTokenSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 54928}, {"name": "tokenToTokenTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "token_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 55019}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeSwapInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 49342}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeTransferInput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "min_eth_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 49532}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeSwapOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 53233}, {"name": "tokenToExchangeTransferOutput", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_tokens_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "max_eth_sold"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "deadline"}, {"type": "address", "name": "recipient"}, {"type": "address", "name": "exchange_addr"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 53423}, {"name": "getEthToTokenInputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_sold"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 5542}, {"name": "getEthToTokenOutputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_bought"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 6872}, {"name": "getTokenToEthInputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "tokens_sold"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 5637}, {"name": "getTokenToEthOutputPrice", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "eth_bought"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 6897}, {"name": "tokenAddress", "outputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1413}, {"name": "factoryAddress", "outputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1443}, {"name": "balanceOf", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_owner"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1645}, {"name": "transfer", "outputs": [{"type": "bool", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_to"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 75034}, {"name": "transferFrom", "outputs": [{"type": "bool", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_from"}, {"type": "address", "name": "_to"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 110907}, {"name": "approve", "outputs": [{"type": "bool", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_spender"}, {"type": "uint256", "name": "_value"}], "constant": false, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 38769}, {"name": "allowance", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [{"type": "address", "name": "_owner"}, {"type": "address", "name": "_spender"}], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1925}, {"name": "name", "outputs": [{"type": "bytes32", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1623}, {"name": "symbol", "outputs": [{"type": "bytes32", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1653}, {"name": "decimals", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1683}, {"name": "totalSupply", "outputs": [{"type": "uint256", "name": "out"}], "inputs": [], "constant": true, "payable": false, "type": "function", "gas": 1713}]


const doReq = async () =>  {
  console.log("uniswapFactoryContract.methods", uniswapFactoryContract.methods)
  const exchangeAddress = await uniswapFactoryContract.methods.getPair('0xeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee', '0x6b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f').call()

  console.log("exchangeAddress", exchangeAddress)
  const exchangeContract = new web3.eth.Contract(UNISWAP_EXCHANGE_ABI, exchangeAddress)
  const res = await exchangeContract.methods.getEthToTokenInputPrice(web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ETHER')).call()
  console.log("res", res);
}

doReq()
```

**Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.**

i'm running this on the mainnet.infura.io/v3/***

this is sushiswap. is something just wrong with the contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Uniswap v2 [docs](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/guides/smart-contract-integration/getting-pair-addresses) for `getPair()` function says:

> *If the pair exists, this function will return its address, else `address(0)` (`0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000`).*

And since you're passing a non-existing pair to the `getPair()` function, it returns the `0x0` address, and assigns this value to the `exchangeAddress` variable.

Then your code is to interact with the 0x0 address, assuming it holds a contract with the `UNISWAP_EXCHANGE_ABI`.

```
// `exchangeAddress` value is 0x0
const exchangeContract = new web3.eth.Contract(UNISWAP_EXCHANGE_ABI, exchangeAddress)
```

And when it calls the `getEthToTokenInputPrice()` method, it doesn't receive any response (there is no contract on the 0x0 address to send a response), which causes the error.

---

You can add a validation after the `getPair()`. If the pair doesn't exist, perform an early return.

```
const exchangeAddress = ...

if (exchangeAddress === '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
  console.log("pair not found");
  return;
}
```

Comment: @TabulaRasa Sushiswap uses the WETH token address as a replacement for ETH. So if can pass the DAI address (`0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F`) as the first param, and the WETH address (`0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2`) as the second param to the `getPair()` function, you get the pair contract address as the result - `0xC3D03e4F041Fd4cD388c549Ee2A29a9E5075882f`.

Comment: thanks!!!!! found this site that has all valid pairs for sushiswap https://analytics.sushi.com/pairs

Comment: one more thing. should i be using a different `UNISWAP_EXCHANGE_ABI` than the one i used in my original question to get the prices? i am currently using https://etherscan.io/address/0x09cabec1ead1c0ba254b09efb3ee13841712be14#code but thats for uniswap. i figured that since sushiswap is just a fork of uniswap, they should be using the same contract exchange ABI. but i keep getting **Error: Returned error: execution reverted**

Comment: @TabulaRasa Sushiswap uses the Uniswap V2 code. I'm not aware of any differences in the contract code, and I'm assuming the contracts are a 100% clone. So if you're getting a revert, it's most likely for a reason related to the actual swap - such as not enough balance or higher slippage than allowed in your tx params.

Comment: i wonder if it has something to do with the fact that my RPC provider is mainnet. if i switched to ropsten, would i need to use a different ABI, sushiswap contract address, and token address for dai/weth ? that area is still fuzzy in my mind

Comment: @TabulaRasa Sushiswap doesn't have official contracts on the Ropsten testnet. Source: https://dev.sushi.com/sushiswap/contracts ... But if they did, the contract source code would most likely be the same (it's a common practice, but theoretically the devs could chose to deploy different contracts on different networks) so the ABI would be the same. Addresses depend on previous choices of the contracts' devs - some could be the same, some could be different.